# What is group manifold of a compact Lie Group?

Tags: manifolds, lie-groups, compact-manifolds

I searched on google the meaning of a **group manifold of a compact lie group** but I didn't get the answer.

A paper on arxiv "Background Independent Quantum Gravity:A Status Report- Abhay Ashtekar" on the page no. 25 talks about this.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Can you perhaps add more context? Maybe some related definition..?

Answer (score 2):

Take the special unitary group $\operatorname{U}(1)$ for example.

It is a group in that it is a set of elements that satisfy the four axioms of a group. Furthermore it satisfies the axioms that are necessary to make it a Lie Group. From here it is a theorem that: sets with a relation satisfying the axioms for a Lie Group have a natural manifold structure associated with them.

Now let's consider this set's natural manifold structure. Unitary matrices in one dimension have $n^2 = 1$ free parameter. The set of all elements of this group can naturally be given the structure of a circle, the manifold $S^1$. So when we talk about the manifold of a group we are referring to the fact that the elements have a natural manifold structure associated with them, as well as a group structure.

Now referring to the paper you cite, there is a separate thing called an action. This is where the group elements, or points in the group manifold, describe transformations on another space, for example the phase space of a particle. We would colloquially say a 'particle evolving on U(1)'.

Answer (score 0):

It should be clear that a group manifold of a compact lie group is the compact lie group because lie groups are manifolds .

Comment: Ok, but exactly *what kind* of objects can have "*group manifold*" and exactly what is that?

Comment: I am a physics student not a mathematics. 

If it is a compact lie group only, then he would have just written compact lie group instead of writing group manifold of a compact lie group. 

The arxiv article given above talks about quantum mechanics on a compact lie group.  
Is it the action of compact lie group on group manifold? "I also don't know what is group manifold."